# Mandelbrot set program not working in JS fiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, fractals, math.js

My script tags tags include a math library called [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) It can handle complex numbers and other advanced math functions.

```
i = 0;
z = math.complex(0, 0);
c = math.complex(-0.75, -0.1);
function Mandelbrot() {
    function Magnitude() {
        a = z.re;
        b = z.im;
        return(math.sqrt(math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2)));
    }
    while (Magnitude() <= 2 && i < 100) {
        z = math.pow(z, 2) + c;
        i++;
    }
    alert(i)
}
Mandelbrot();
```

This program is suposed to be the basis of a program that I'm making to graph the Mandelbrot set.

Here's the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noahthefuzzy/ryvtL3Lq/1/

Comment: `z` is an object.  you can't raise an object to a power.  in other words...`math.pow(z, 2)` is throwing an error...

Comment: Although, actually it’s not `Math.pow` but this library `math.pow` thing… and `z` at that point is defined…

Comment: I made the suggested changes. Here's the new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noahthefuzzy/ryvtL3Lq/2/ still doesnt work though

Comment: @Liam Forget about the changes… if `math.pow` can handle complex numbers then it’s fine. The problem is that `z` is undefined at that point…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [math.add](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/add.html) instead of `+` to add c, because c is an object storing a complex number:

```
z = math.add(math.pow(z, 2), c);
```

Comment: That’s what I thought. When `math.pow(z, 2) + c` executes he gets `"0-0.75 - 0.1i"`. He’d need to parse it as a complex number again.

Comment: Thank you so much. In case your interested I'm doing a stupid math art project and I thought I would make it cool